# How to align tikz box with itemized bullet?

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

I have the following code that produces the result below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\hour}[1]{\tikz{
  \node[draw, rounded corners=1mm,text depth=0.8ex,line width=1pt] (a) {\Large{}#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item \hour{Hour}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would like to:

- Center the text inside the box
- Align the center of the box with the bullet

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

1. Set a baseline with the node (a). With that you'll have the right alignment w.r.t. normal size text. If you want better alignment for large text you can change the size of the bullet too.
2. Put a `\strut` in the node (or not). With the `\strut` all the boxes will have the same height. Without it the text will be vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {enumitem}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\firsthour}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(a.base)]
    \node[draw,rounded corners=1mm,line width=1pt,inner sep=0.3ex] (a) {\Large\strut#1};% <-- We don't want a space here
}

\newcommand{\secondhour}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(a.base)]
    \node[draw,rounded corners=1mm,line width=1pt,inner sep=0.7ex] (a) {\Large#1};% <-- We don't want a space here
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item \firsthour{Hour} is aligned (w.r.t. normal size text),
    \item \firsthour{Hour} is not centered, but
    \item \firsthour{3 p.m.} is centered.
  \end{itemize}
  \bigskip

  \begin{itemize}[label=\Large$\bullet$]
    \item \firsthour{Hour} is aligned (w.r.t. large size text),
    \item \firsthour{Hour} is not centered, but
    \item \firsthour{3 p.m.} is centered.
  \end{itemize}
  \bigskip

  \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item \secondhour{Hour} is aligned (w.r.t. normal size text),
    \item \secondhour{Hour} is centered, and
    \item \secondhour{3 p.m.} is centered.
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With some manual tweaking of node's baseline position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\hour}[1]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{
  \node[draw, rounded corners=1mm, very thick,
         text depth=0.25ex, 
        font=\Large] (a) {#1}}
                      }

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$]
    \item \hour{Hour}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]